# What does if(file.is_image) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

And what would be the equivalent for sound?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like somebody created a custom type and `is_image` is one of its members.

My guess would be that it is checking to see if the file is an image file and returning true if it is and false if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object `file` is defined somewhere in one of the scripts run by this certain page. And `is_image` is its member (most probably a `Boolean` property).

The statement actually means one of these:

- `if (file.is_image is defined at all) then do something` or
- `if (file.is_image is true) then do something`