# Javascript checking if file is mp3-format?

Tags: javascript

How do I do this? Something that begins with

```
if(file."something?"
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? What if `file`? WTH are you trying do do? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258811/what-does-iffile-is-image-mean-in-javascript

Comment: The only foolproof way would be to download the file and examine it, and you can't do that in Javascript.  The web server might lie in the Content-Type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you simply want to check that a filename ends in ".mp3" you can do the following.

```
// Assuming variable "file" is the filename
if(file.indexOf(".mp3") == file.length - 4) {
    // File type is .mp3
}
```

If you want to be doubly sure that the filename represents an *actual* mp3 file, you could send an XMLHttpRequest to the server and retrieve the HEAD, reading the `Content-type`.

Although your question seems a bit ambiguous to what "file" is ... It looks like `file` could be a custom type that represents a handler in an API or such, and in that case, the API documentation should help you out.

Comment: in this case it would be better to use `file.lastIndexOf(".mp3")`

Answer (score 3):

Detecting a MIME type based on a file extension is unreliable. Don't.

Try sending an HTTP `HEAD` request using AJAX, then get the `Content-Type` returned.